# Android jdk installation - cannot install jdk manually

Tags: java, android, sdk

actually  I am newbie here..I was trying to install jdk manually ( File > Project Structure). I selected the jdk location  and clicked ok. but nothing happened actually.  I disappointed. then I reopened Android studio and got a message please  configure jdk.I created java home and installed java se development kit before installing Android studio. as I got jdk installation error, I tried to install jdk from project structure....... but nothing happened actually.....

help me to install jdk correctly....

Comment: Can you list in detail what steps you followed in trying to install? Can you also include the exact error message(s) you received?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are installing JDK for Android studio. If yes, this will might help you.

Guidelines for installing Android Studio

1. First we have to download Android studio Setup for installation. We can download it from here https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html 
   But I have downloaded Android studio from here: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/2.1.2.0/android-studio-bundle-143.2915827-windows.exe  (version 2.1.2)
2. Secondly download jdk as per your OS requirements i.e. if you are running windows 32 bit you will download 32 bit version of jdk
   And if your OS is 64 bit you can download according jdk

Install JDK before installing Android studio, it’s a good practice, 
Now install JDK which you have downloaded, follow next steps:
3.  Double click the jdk’s .exe file which we have downloaded in 2nd step.
4.  Popup will appear, click yes. Further it will open installation wizard, click Next

5. Click next
6. It will do some required processes
7. Choose the destination which you want, but I will stick to this default destination path and Click Next
8. Now it will do some required processes
9. Its done, now click on close

Now we have to set environment variable JAVA_HOME and describe its path. 
10. Right click on this pc and click Properties,

And this window will be opened and click on Advanced System Settings

11. Now this window will appear and here click on Environment Variables button
12. Now it’ll appear this window and you should click New
13. Now it write JAVA_HOME in variable name field and go to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131 and copy this path. Now past this path in variable value field, and press OK 
    Click OK on Environment variables window 
    Click OK on system properties window

Now JDK installation is completed!

Now it’s Time to install Android Studio, so let’s start.
14. Now double click to run the android studio’s .exe file, which we have downloaded in 1st step. I have downloaded version 2.1.2

15. Setup will start loading and after 100% loading a popup widow will appear (asking for you want to install this software or not) you should click yes.

If you clicked yes to popup window, it will appear installation wizard. And you should click next

16. Click Next

And License Agreement will be open, you should click I Agree

17. If you want to change destination, change it but I will stick to this destination and Click Next
18. And click install
19. It’ll start extracting files

After this it’ll extract Android sdk

After 100% extraction, now click on Complete and next window will be opened, click Finish.
20. Now it will start

21. This popup will appear and you should click second radio button, if you do not have previous version or you do not want to import any settings from previous version of android studio. And you should click first radio button instead and click OK
22. wizard for download required components will open (This will need your internet data),

After downloading finish button will be activated, you should click Finish
Finally your Android studio is installed, now you can start the new project or open existing project :)